# How to setup badge count firebase push notification in ios?

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have successfully setup my backend to send notification using "firebase-admin". However, I am having trouble setting up the badge count for my ios. I am currently using react native and node.js typescript for backend.

My backend admin when sending looks like this:

```
const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "title",
                body: `body`,
              //badge: 1 this throws an error
            },
            token: receiverFcmToken
        };

        try{
            await admin.messaging().send(payload).then((response) => {
                console.log("success);
            });
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your payload should look like this:

```
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: "title",
        body: `body`,
    },
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          badge: 1,
        },
      },
    },
    token: receiverFcmToken
};
```